# Data automatically removed from the inserted fields at the time of taking photo

Tags: iphone

During the registration part of my app, the user enters some text in some text fields and then I show a camera view so the user can take a picture.

After taking the photo and going back to the view with the text fields, the text previously entered into the fields is gone and the fields are empty.

Comment: Are you release the fillup view or not?

Comment: Show a little more code ;). Do you some stuff like `textfield.text = @""` in your ViewControllers `viewWillAppear:animated:` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about an app you're developing, right? It's probable that the use of the image picker generates a memory warning which causes any view controller whose view is not onscreen at the moment (i.e., your registration form view controller) to unload its view, thereby losing all the information that is contained in the controls.

Moral of the story: don't ever store data in your views. Be prepared for a view to be deallocated at any time it's not visible. Always copy data from a view to a model object after it has been edited.